# How do I get/find an already running child process?

Tags: node.js, child-process

If I spawn a child process in `index.js`:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const terminal = spawn('./start.sh')
```

How would I access this process from another file (something like `processes.get(pid)`)? I want to be able to access the whole `ChildProcess` class so I can use methods such as `stdin.write` in the second file.

**EDIT:** I don't want the second file to start the process every time the second file is executed. The process has to be started from `index.js` and the second file would just access that running process without starting it again.

---

I've tried using `module.exports = { terminal }` and having this in the second file:

```js
const { terminal } = require('./index.js')
terminal.stdin.write('some command here')
```

but that spawns the process again and I can't have more than 1 of that process running at the same time.

In my situation, I also can't write to the socket in `/proc/[pid]/fd/0`, so I can't write to `stdin` using that method.

Comment: Could you share your source codes?

Answer (score 0):

Script 1, that will run the child process

```
module.exports.startprocess=function startpro(){
var childProces_file1 = require("child_process").spawn('bash', ['./hello.sh'],{stdio: "inherit"})
exports.childProces_file1=childProces_file1;
 }
```

Script 2. that will call the function

```
var child_process_file2 =require("./file1.js")
child_process_file2.startprocess();
console.log("child process id is",child_process_file2.childProces_file1.pid);
```

[image]

**Updated:**

So you just need to export the pid

```
var childProces_file1 = require("child_process").spawn('bash', ['./hello.sh'],{stdio: "inherit"})
exports.childProces_file1=childProces_file1;
 childProcess.on('data', function(data){
    process.stdout.write("python script output",data);
    exports.pydata=data;
});
```

So the file is able to get the pid

```
var child_process_file2 =require("./file1.js")
console.log("child process id is",child_process_file2.childProces_file1.pid);
if ( child_process_file2.pydata){
    console.log(child_process_file2.pydata)
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough in my question, but I don't want script 2 to start the process every time it is executed. I want the process to be started in file 1 and file 2 to get the process that is running in file 1. The process is always running.

Comment: Your updated answer is very similar to what I already tried: exporting the child process and requiring it from another file. That also spawns the process again. I don't know if it's possible, but I want to get the `ChildProcess` object (and therefore the running process) that is spawned in the second file.